# Terminal messages related to executed command replaced by “tmux” when using Zsh

Tags: linux, tmux

When I'm inside a running tmux installation and run a command that errors out, sometimes `tmux` will replace the name of the original command.

ie. if `test` is a directory, then this happens:

```
jameswright in ~ at portal1 via ⬢ v12.13.0           
➜ rm test                                     
tmux: cannot remove ‘test’: Is a directory
```

Note this behavior doesn't occur when using `cp` or `ls`. This is on Linux using Zsh. The issue does not occur when using Bash and in `.tmux.conf`, neither `default-command` nor `default-shell` are set.

However, if I prefix the command with `env -i` — as in `env -i rm test` — I am properly seeing `rm` as the command and not `tmux`:

```
➜ env -i rm test
rm: cannot remove 'test': Is a directory
```

Also, if I use `strace` to try and debug the problem -- using `strace -fostrace.out rm test`-- I am also correctly seeing `rm` instead of `tmux`:

```
➜ strace -fostrace2.out rm test
rm: cannot remove 'test': Is a directory
```

Any ideas as to *how* this could happen?

I assume the error message should be generated by the offending command, but this appears to say otherwise.

Running `/bin/rm test` — using the full binary path — has the same result as above.

Also, `rm --help` also replaces `rm` with `tmux`:

```
➜ rm --help
Usage: tmux [OPTION]... FILE...
Remove (unlink) the FILE(s).

  -f, --force           ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
....
....
To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',
use one of these commands:
  tmux -- -foo

  tmux ./-foo
```

Comment: Is `rm` a regular binary executable? or a wrapper script? or a function? Or a builtin in your particular shell? What shell are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure whether rm is a binary. `rm` is aliased to `rm -i` and `where rm` returns `/bin/rm`. I'm using zsh.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Just as a test, I tried to replicate using bash instead of zsh and I don't see the same behavior (so the error returns `rm: cannot remove 'test': Is a directory`)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Done. See edit. I'm not sure how definitely check whether `rm` is from GNU coreutils or not, but the man page for `rm` is at least from GNU coreutils 8.23

Comment: @Nicholas Marriott I've answered your questions in the edit.

Comment: Also note that this is same system from the unresolved [tmux issue #2137](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2137) issue, so this may result in the same conclusion of "something's acting up with zsh".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the `ARGV0` environment variable to `tmux`. In this case, it is the `tmux` AppImage that is setting the variable.

According to [AppImage Documentation](https://docs.appimage.org/packaging-guide/environment-variables.html#type-2-appimage-runtime), the `$ARGV0` variable is set to the name/path called to execute the AppImage. So running `tmux` will set `ARGV0=tmux`.

However, starting `tmux` using the absolute path to the AppImage `/users/jameswright/.local/bin/tmux` gives:

```
➜ rm test
/users/jameswright/.local/bin/tmux: cannot remove ‘test’: Is a directory
```

An immediate fix to this to run `unset ARGV0` while in the tmux session.

This issue was fixed in the [tmux AppImage](https://github.com/nelsonenzo/tmux-appimage/issues/2) repository. Otherwise, [extracting the AppImage](https://docs.appimage.org/user-guide/run-appimages.html#extract-the-contents-of-an-appimage) and calling the extracted binary itself will also fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything obvious in the rm source. It is interesting that it doesn't happen in bash.

See if you can reproduce by running:

```
/bin/rm test
```

Which will definitely rule out any wrapper scripts or aliases.

If it still happens, you could install strace and run, for example:

```
strace -fostrace.out rm test
```

And you may be able to look at strace.out and see if it is being passed tmux as its first argument (I think it is the first few lines).

Also perhaps check if `rm --help` shows tmux as well.

Another thing worth checking is: `env -i rm test` to rule out any environment variable causing trouble.

Comment: Progress! See edit 2, but `env -i` did fix the problem. Now to track down the guilty variable...

Comment: Much like your other two deleted “answers” — [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1550272/167207) and [this other one](https://superuser.com/a/1550203/167207) — this is not an answer at all. This is simply a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @JamesWright It's probably not about a variable. It's about who's calling `rm` and providing `argv[0]` for it. It looks like `env` does it right and `zsh` doesn't. I think `zsh` tries to "improve" `rm` (compare [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/135084/108618)), so maybe calling `rm` is a special case, special piece of code, and there's a bug in the procedure.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski If I start another zsh login (`zsh -l`) the issue no longer appears. Any debugging tips would be helpful. Not zsh options I can see are relevant in this case.

Comment: kamil-maciorowski's link is a good find, it does seem like zsh is messing with rm here and getting it slightly wrong. Are you saying it happens if you do `zsh -l` but not if you start zsh the way you normally do? You may have to ask the zsh developers or wait and see if a zsh expert comes along.

Comment: Here's something. Do you have `ARGV0` set in the environment? Try `echo $ARGV0`. zsh will use that as `argv[0]` for new commands if it is set, although one would think that would affect `cp` as well as `rm`...

Comment: If not `ARGV0`, the only other thing I can see where zsh replaces `arvg[0]` is from its `PATH` hash, maybe it is getting messed up somehow - does running `rehash` fix it by any chance? No idea how that could happen though.

Comment: Well, you said it didn't work if you did `/bin/rm`, so probably can forget the hash actually...

Comment: `echo $ARGV0` returns `tmux`.

Comment: @NicholasMarriott I think the issue is my use of the AppImage version of `tmux`. According to [AppImage Documentation](https://docs.appimage.org/packaging-guide/environment-variables.html#type-2-appimage-runtime), a type 2 AppImage sets the `ARGV0` environment variable to the relative path of the AppImage, which is `tmux` since it is in my PATH as that.

Comment: @NicholasMarriott I've edited your pseudo-answer to reflect the solution I've created. You should be able to accept the edit. Once it is accepted (or edited to your liking), I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: OK great so the problem is AppImage, that's great. I wonder why it sets that, I guess it makes sense for some applications. If there is an AppImage of zsh, how do they stop it setting it for everything?? May be worth pointing it out here https://github.com/nelsonenzo/tmux-appimage/issues, perhaps something can be done.